# Ember how to bindAttr with prefix

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I have a simple button with action to which I'm binding id:

```
<button {{action goTo item}} {{bindAttr id="item.id"}} >{{item.name}}</button>
```

Which gives me `id='123'`, is that possible to prefix the id somehow to get ie. `id='navbtn_123'` ?

Comment: Perfect use case for computed properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a computed property in your 'item' definition

```
idPrefix: 'navbtn_',
idForElement = function(){
    return this.get('idPrefix')+this.get('id')
}.property('id','idPrefix')
```

and the in your handlebars

```
<button {{action goTo item}} {{bindAttr id="item.idForElement"}} >{{item.name}}</button>
```